# Understanding Bounded Generic Parameter to a constructor

Tags: java, generics

I am confused, why is the first code snippet compiling but the second isn't?

I would assume that in both cases the generic parameter T describes the same set of possible types and thus they are equivalent.

**First example**

```
public class Main {

    static Function<B, Integer> f = (b) -> 1;

    Main() {
        this(f);
    }

    <T extends A> Main(Function<T, Integer> f) {

    }

}

class A {    }

class B extends A {    }
```

**Second example:**

```
public class Main<T extends A> {

    static Function<B, Integer> f = (b) -> 1;

    Main() {
        this(f);
    }

    Main(Function<T, Integer> f) {

    }

}

class A {    }

class B extends A {    }
```

Yields the error:

> `The constructor Main <T>(Function<B,Integer>) is undefined`

Comment: what does your error message tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first code, the `T` parameter is scoped to the method :

```
<T extends A> Main(Function<T, Integer> f) {

}
```

It uses inference of the target (client declared type return) to determinate the `T` value.
So it can only compile while the first type of the `Function` is a `A` or a subclass of `A` to respect the `<T extends A>` constraint.
For example declare these other classes :

```
class B extends A {    }

class C extends A {    }

class D extends B {    }
```

And these will also work :

```
static Function<B, Integer> fb = (b) -> 1;
static Function<C, Integer> fc = (b) -> 1;
static Function<D, Integer> fd = (b) -> 1;
```

In the second code, you want to pass a `Function<B, Integer>` declared variable to the `Main` constructor that relies on the `T` generic type of the class  :

```
public class Main<T extends A> {

    Main(Function<T, Integer> f) {

    }

}
```

The problem is that here `T` could be `A`, `B` or any other subclass of `A` according to the generic type used by the client of the class.
 So `Function<B, Integer>` is not assignable to `Function<T, Integer>` and the compilation fails.

Answer (score 3):

On your second example you introduce the type parameter T at class level, however you will pass a fixed function using class B always. What if you instantiated Main with Main«A»? Your code is not type safe.
In your first example this is not an issue since the type parameter on the function is only determined with every call.

Answer (score 0):

Those examples are not the same.

Example 1 - only the constructor #2 is generic, but constructor #1 and the class not.

So the compiler only has to infer type of the argument for constr #2 in constr #1. And that is fine and possible.

Example 2 - the whole class is generic.
So the compiler already for constr #1 uses type `T extends A`. And now it checks call to constr #2. It figures out that `T extends A` is not equal `B` (`T` can be any other class, that extends `A`).

To clarify - for generic class, the type inference (resolution of the generic type) cannot happen in the constructor. It happens, where the constructor is called from outside. Inside it's already given exactly as defined.

Compared to that example one only uses method (constructor) type inference, which can happen perfectly in constr #1.